# How to Distribute iphone application to app store using paid Account id

Tags: iphone

Hi Dear i have register apple account id can u plz guide the steps how do i have to upload may application to app store?

if it is possible to suggest me also the link to deploy at ad-hoc level?

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See first below link it covers basic steps:

```
http://arstechnica.com/apple/2009/04/app-store-lessons-dealing-with-pink-uploads-of-doom/
```

Also see this link: `http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/AboutYourFirstAppStoreSubmission/AboutYourFirstAppStoreSubmission.html`

Comment: Also if you have another doubts then also see this link: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/app_store_guide.html

Comment: Thanks Vishal for reply.i want to learn more about iOS Portal Provisional process the certificates either development or distribution is there any help or guide that help to understand i am new in app Process .

Comment: See these links all are describe about iOS portal & also describe about how to make development provisioning file & same like that we can make Ad-hoc portal...http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/CreatingandDownloadingaDistributionProvisioningProfile/CreatingandDownloadingaDistributionProvisioningProfile.html

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/ProvisioningPortal_Recipes/AddingaDeviceIDtoYourDevelopmentTeam/AddingaDeviceIDtoYourDevelopmentTeam.html & https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/gettingstarted/